# How do I extract onclick event Javascript text from BeautifulSoup scrape to then use with Selenium execute_script?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with an internal website and using Selenium and Beautifulsoup to pull a paystub for multiple employees. I first use Selenium to open the site, run a quick javascript to generate a table of results, and then use BeautifulSoup to find the particular stub I need to review based upon the pay amount.

The resulting table includes a link for each paystub with an "onclick" event that generates a list of javascript commands. There is no other way to identify the hyperlink for each paystub, so I focused on finding the onclick javascript I need to run to find the correct paystub.

**In summary, I'm just needing to extract the 13 different jv commands from the payhref variable below that I retrieve using BeautifulSoup. Then I can use Selenium to run that script with execute_script. However, I cannot seem to logically extract that text from payhref.**

```
empid = 000000000
conum= 01
driver.get('http://www.website.com/hrs/payroll/checks/pay_summary.asp')
javascript = "document.querySelector('#txtFromDate').value = '12/1/2019';  document.querySelector('#spanFormletContentsFormletInput > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr.alignTextCenter > td.alignTextCenter > input').click();" % (conum, empid)
driver.execute_script(javascript)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
paylink= soup.find(string="541.80")
paylink_parent = paylinks.find_parent("tr")
payhref = paylink_parent.find('a')
```

payhref then returns this HTML:

```
<a href="/" onclick="document.frmInitial.hidSSN.value='000000000';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidCompany.value='01';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidUSERID.value='XXXXXXX';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidInsertID.value='XXXXXX';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidPeriodEndDate.value='2019-08-17';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidICC.value='4090';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidStation.value='132';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidDraftNumber.value='00004806';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidManualType.value='H';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidRate.value='.0000';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidReportingDate.value='2019-08-20';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidActionCode.value='2';
                                    document.frmInitial.hidReturnCode.value='0';
                                    this.href='javascript:submitForm(2)'">
                                    132</a>
```

What I'm needing to extract from payhref:

```
document.frmInitial.hidSSN.value='000000000';
document.frmInitial.hidCompany.value='01';
document.frmInitial.hidUSERID.value='XXXXXXX';
document.frmInitial.hidInsertID.value='XXXXXX';
document.frmInitial.hidPeriodEndDate.value='2019-08-17';
document.frmInitial.hidICC.value='4090';
document.frmInitial.hidStation.value='132';
document.frmInitial.hidDraftNumber.value='00004806';
document.frmInitial.hidManualType.value='H';
document.frmInitial.hidRate.value='.0000';
document.frmInitial.hidReportingDate.value='2019-08-20';
document.frmInitial.hidActionCode.value='2';
document.frmInitial.hidReturnCode.value='0';
```

**Updated Solution**

```
onclicktext = payhref.get('onclick')
```

onclicktext returns:

```
"document.frmInitial.hidSSN.value='000000000';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidCompany.value='01';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidUSERID.value='XXXXXXX';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidInsertID.value='XXXXXXX';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidPeriodEndDate.value='2019-08-17';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidICC.value='4090';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidStation.value='132';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidDraftNumber.value='00004806';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidManualType.value='H';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidRate.value='.0000';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidReportingDate.value='2019-08-20';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidActionCode.value='2';\n    \t\t\t\t\t\t        document.frmInitial.hidReturnCode.value='0';\n    \t\t\t                    this.href='javascript:submitForm(2)'"
```

I then reformatted onclicktext to make it executable by Selenium's execute_script:

```
onclicktext = onclicktext.replace('\n','')
onclicktext = onclicktext.replace('\t','')
onclicktext = onclicktext.replace("this.href='javascript:submitForm(2)'",'')
driver.execute_script(onclicktext)
driver.execute_script('submitForm(2)')
```

I'm sure there is a more Pythonic way to do this, but using the .get('onclick') was certainly what I was missing.

Comment: try this: `onclicktext = payhref.get('onclick')`

Comment: That was very helpful. So now I can remove the \n and \t with replace.
`onclicktext = onclicktext.replace('\n','')`

Comment: just posted it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an element in a HTML Tag you can use the .get() method in bs4.

```
onclicktext = payhref.get('onclick')
```

This variable will contain all content in the 'onclick' element.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the link just use attribute value `onclick` and then **split** and **exclude** the last item

```
payhref = paylink_parent.find('a')
for item in payhref['onclick'].split(';')[:-1]:
    print(item.strip() +";")
```

Comment: This was also very helpful, but unless I'm incorrect I need the ';' to remain in the javascript text in order to pass it to Selenium's execute_script function.

Comment: You can add this `;` as well